# What m i doing wrong in this code i have been stuck at

Tags: python, parsing

I'm trying to make a request and parse the current btc price..

my code

```
import requests
import json



r = requests.get('https://blockchain.info/ticker')

k = r.text


Rate = json.loads(k)


print(Rate["last"])
```

and the output is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wifi2.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(Rate["last"])
KeyError: 'last'
```

how can i fix it?
thanks

Comment: Did you try `print(Rate)`?  See what it actually contains?

Comment: your requests get empty?

Comment: @TomKarzes yeah i tried :) i get the response in json formate. if u open the link u can see it. Dor-Ron explained it and its working fine :)

Comment: @nub whenever you get data from the internet, then first see the format of your data always AND then get your desired result. Happy learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a sample entry from the URL you provided:

```
"USD" : {"15m" : 11237.41, "last" : 11237.41, "buy" : 11237.41, "sell" : 11237.41, "symbol" : "$"}
```

They Key is the shorthand for the currency, and it's value is another dictionary, such that:

```
'USD' -> {..., "last": 11237.41, ...}
```

To get the value of the last key of the inner dictionary, you need to do for example:

```
print(Rate["USD"]["last"])
```

This returns the dictionary associated with the first key, then the value associated with the **last** key of the inner dictionary.